# Why am I not able to import modules from package?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created a package named `math`. Inside this package I have created 2 files:

- `simple.py`
- `__init__.py`

And outside the package `math` is my file `main.py`.

`__init__.py` looks like this:

```
a=1
```

This is the contents of `main.py`:

```
import math
print(math.a)
```

The output should be `1`, but I am getting no output.

Even in case of
`main.py`:

```
from math import simple
print(simple.add(1,2))
```

I am getting the error as: `cannot import name simple`.

Can someone tell where I am going wrong?

Comment: the correct name is `__init__.py`, not `init.py`. Also, math is a builtin package, so I advise you to change the name to avoid name clashes.

Comment: Oh yes! It is working perfectly fine now. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

There are three leads to this problem.

1. `init.py` should be called `__init__.py`,
2. `math` is also the name of a builtin package. Good chances are it is loaded instead of your package, and doesn't define `a`,
3. In order for your package to be discoverable, ensure that the root directory where `math` is defined is in your pythonpath (`PYTHONPATH` environment variable).

Comment: please note that OP was using `__init__` and not `init`. It was just a formatting issue